# Почему указатель не сдвигается на переменную?

Tags: c

Воссоздаю функцию `strdup(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)`, и мне необходимо
сдвинуть указаель `s` на значение `start`, но какое бы не было значение `start`, выводится мусор. Причем на число с клавиатуры все конечно же хорошо.
Исходный код:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    char    *str;

    if(!(str = (char *)malloc(len + 1)))
        return(NULL);
    s+= start;
    printf("s %c\n", *s);
    while(len-- && *s)
        *str++ = *s++;
    *str = '\0';
    return (&str[0]);
}

int main()
{
    char dest[40] = "Hello my friend";
    printf("ft_substr :%s\n", ft_substr(dest, 6, 9));
}

//Result
s  $
ft_substr :$
```

Comment: `*str = '\0'`. Ну и скобки после return не нужны.

Comment: За `*str = '\0'` спасибо, не заметил, но суть вопроса не поменялась.

Comment: Тогда дайте такой код, который можно запустить и увидеть, что он не работает. См. [mcve].

Comment: Покажите, что и как вы выводите, может, проблемы там. Особенно смущает вот это - *Причем на число с клавиатуры все конечно же хорошо* - какая разница, *откуда* число?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat поменял

Comment: @Harry добавил вывод. Про число с клавиатуры имелось в виду `s+=32` или `s+=5`

Comment: Вы возвращаете `str`, но ведь он уже сдвинут на конец строки. Еще, хедеры пропущены, и в main лишняя звездочка.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все поменял, все равно вывод тот же

Comment: Не все, первое предложение прочитайте еще раз.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но я же возвращаю адрес на нулевой элемент массива.

Comment: То, что вернул вызов `malloc` запомните в отдельной переменной и возвращайте её. `&str[0] == &(*(str+0)) == str+0 == str`.

Comment: @wololo понял! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотрите, **куда** указывает `str` по окончании наботы? На нулевой символ.

```
*str = '\0';
return (&str[0]);
```

Вот вы его и выводите. Сделайте так, например:

```
char    *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    char    *str, *ret;

    if(!(str = (char *)malloc(len + 1)))
        return(NULL);
    ret = str;
    s+= start;
    printf("s %c\n", *s);
    while(len-- && *s)
        *str++ = *s++;
    *str = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```